# Select rows from Dataframe and include another column python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I an new to python, How can I select columns from dataframe which end with **_old** and include  **B column** as final output? Here is my dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': 'foo bar foo bar foo bar foo foo'.split(),
                   'B': 'james weker john mark jane der liv vam'.split(),
                   'C_old': np.arange(8), 'D_old': np.arange(8) * 2})
print(df1)
```

I have tried this which only selects columns which endswith **_old** but I what to include B column in the output

```
df1[df1.columns[pd.Series(df1.columns).str.endswith('_old')]]
```

My EXPECTED output should look like this

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
                   'B': 'james weker john mark jane der liv vam'.split(),
                   'C_old': np.arange(8), 'D_old': np.arange(8) * 2})
print(df1)
```

Comment: Is there really no way to obtain a list of the columns that you want other than through string operations on their name? It seems like something that should be avoided if at all possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) with regex - `$` for ends of string, `|` for `or` and `^B$` for select by column `B` (`^` is for start of string)

```
df = df1.filter(regex='_old$|^B$')
```

You can select by masks - use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for select all rows (`:`) and columns by condition:

```
df = df1.loc[:, df1.columns.str.endswith('_old') | (df1.columns == 'B')]
```

Or use [`Index.union`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.union.html) for add `B` to columns:

```
df = df1[df1.columns[df1.columns.str.endswith('_old')].union(['B'])]
print (df)
       B  C_old  D_old
0  james      0      0
1  weker      1      2
2   john      2      4
3   mark      3      6
4   jane      4      8
5    der      5     10
6    liv      6     12
7    vam      7     14
```